# Symfony2 personnalisation attr radio buttons

Tags: symfony, twig

I can not find the opportunity to customize the attributes on radio buttons separately, because I want to insert a `title` tag and `data-toggle="tooltip"` to display a tooltip on every radio buttons

```
$builder
        ->add('type', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array(
                '0' => 'Demande', // Here personnalise attr
                '1' => 'Recherche', // Here personnalise attr
            ),
            'expanded'  => true,
        ))
```

Thank you !

Comment: Providing the `attr` option to the expanded choice field will render those attributes on the checkbox elements.

Comment: No this is not what I want to do with this code because I will have the same title tag for the two radio buttons ... But what I want to do is have a different title tag for each radio button

Answer (score 0):

Use attr option:

```
$builder
        ->add('type', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array(
                '0' => 'Demande', // Here personnalise attr
                '1' => 'Recherche', // Here personnalise attr
            ),
            'expanded'  => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
                'title' => 'a title'
            ),
        ))
```

Comment: No this is not what I want to do with this code because I will have the same title tag for the two radio buttons ... But what I want to do is have a different title tag for each radio button